# Rendering divs in twig template

Tags: html, css, twig

I am new to twig or HTML/CSS and I need help with rendering divs using twig template. Here is the screen shot of what my webpage currently looks like:
[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoOtN.png)

You can see that the divs come one below the other and one has to scroll up and down to view the contents. I want the divs display side by side. I have tried with CSS, it wont work. Please let me know if any changes in twig template or CSS would help me achieve it. Here is my code for the twig template:

```
<div id="textcontent">
{% set field = data|slice(2) %}
{% set field = field|slice(0, -1) %}

 <div class="col-md-6 grid-container"> 
  {% for item in field %}
    {% if item.uniqueid and  item.uniqueid > 0 %}
      {% if item.content %}
       <div class="source-box text">
        <p> {{ item.content|raw }} </p>
       </div>

      {% endif %}
      {% elseif item.content %}
        <p> {% trans %} Content not present. {% endtrans %} </p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Here is what I did in css:

```
.grid-container {

   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

And it shows something like this on webpage:
[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWLOx.png)

It is not the desired display.

Also following some comments, I am pasting the screenshot of the segment of html that displays the divs above. How can I increase the width? I have tried to put width : 100% but it wont work.:
[See html segment here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5bs6.png)

Comment: _"I have tried with CSS, it wont work"_ - Please show us what you've tried (the css) and the result of it. Also include if you're using some CSS-framework.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php / twig. It's better to post the generated `html` rather than the twig template. As for your question, look into flex / grid